# Display open handle ids in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, debugging

Is there a way to display all the open handles of a process in IDA Pro while debugging it?

I'm debugging a 64-bit binary on Windows OS with the win64_remotex64.exe as the debugging server.

I want to display the list of all the open handles in the process:

```
Open file handles
Open registry handles
Open socket handles
```

Debuggers such as Olly Debugger allow to see the complete list. Is it possible to see the same in IDA Pro?

Information should be as shown below:

```
handle_id - path to the file
```

Thanks.